# "kotlin-kapt" vs "annotationProcessor()"?

Tags: android, annotation-processing, kapt

What is the basic core difference between:

- `kotlin-kapt`
- `annotationProcessor()`

Also, what's the working behavior of these in *Kotlin/Java*?

I researched a lot about this topic but I'm a little bit confused. So, I need to learn more to clear my concepts.

Answer (score 2):

- **kapt**: Default annotation processor for **Kotlin** projects, useful to reference generated code at compile time in a kotlin project. In order to use it you should use the `kotlin-kapt` plugin. It also takes care of java classes

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.7.10"
}
```

and the related dependency:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    kapt("groupId:artifactId:version")
}
```

- **annotationProcessor**: gradle directive to specify your own annotationProcessor or a third party one. For example, in the old android projects was common to use Butterknife library that has its own annotation processor:

```kotlin
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
}
```

In general, an `annotation processor` is useful to generate code automatically from annotations (for butternife, for example `@BindView`) and this is true both for kapt and for a random third-party annotation processor.